# $this function in PHP with multiple arrow operator ->

Tags: php

I am fairly new in PHP and want to ask a question. I know if you want to access a properties or method within a class or object you can use `$this->properties` or `$this->method`.

But I encountered a code like this `$this->context->cart`

Can someone please explain the meaning behind this code ?

If there is another similar question already being asked in SO can you please provide me the link, I will check it out.

Big Thanks

Comment: Context is probably a property of this class that is an instance of another class.

Comment: It is a nested property or method. It'll mainly come up in object oriented code where an object contains another object as a property which itself has properties and or methods.

Comment: In case of a property, the property contains an object that has properties and methods itself. In case of a method, the method returns an object, either itself - so that you can chain methods - or another object.

Comment: And one correction to your own statement for the sake of precision: `$this`does _not_ allow access to properties or methods of a _class_ but _only_ of an object.

Comment: Hi guys, so cart is a properties from context class ? is my understanding correct ?

Comment: @myd07 yes. it's correct. see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42699561/2302051)

Answer (score 4):

See and try it:

```
class class1 {

    public $properties;
    public $context;

    function __construct(){

        $this->properties = '$properties in class1';
        $this->context = new class2(); // instance of class2

    }
}

class class2 {

    public $cart;

    function __construct(){

        $this->cart = '$cart in class2';

    }

}

$obj = new class1();

echo $obj->properties;
echo $obj->context->cart;
```

Answer (score 0):

context is instance of another class for retrive method or property of that class this is use